# Multiple concurrent static hosting contexts

Tags: node.js

If I have a project directory that looks like the following:

```
/
    custom_assets
        File1.txt
    generic_assets
        File2.txt
```

Is there a node http server implementation that would allow me to host both directories from the same root url?

For example:

```
http://localhost/File1.txt
```

Or

```
http://localhost/File2.txt
```

Almost like as if the two directories were merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) which is a popular node web application framework can do it.
Using two static [middlewares](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) should do the trick.

Your code should look like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/custom_assets'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/generic_assets'));
```

Comment: Yes (with precedence to the one specified first in case of conflict)